# How to do Root Operations in Web Interface

Tags: linux, web, interface, privileges

How can I safely do root operations in a web interface?

For example change a user password, mount something, reboot some services.
I won't run it with root privileges. Also I won't allow the web user to access these things.
I need something like a second daemon that will do these things.

How would you do that?